# MVC 4 Error with jquery.val

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

i am having problems with Jquery validation (client side),
it was working well i dont know what happen nw it dont work, here i have some screenshot that may help you to understand the problem 
[image]

and here is my layout :
[image]

and 
[image]

Comment: can't see clearly in the screenshot. I think you need to update the jquery files too

Comment: Already Updated  and  have the same problem

Comment: Please do not post pictures where you should be posting actual code or error messages.   Otherwise, others will not be able to find this thread via the search function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that in your BundleConfig you include

```
        BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/validate")
            .Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
            ));
```

I believe it should be

```
        BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/validate")
            .Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive*",
            ));
```

You are also missing this file (I can't see it in Solution Explorer):

```
"~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
```

These are all **needed files** in the right **order** for jquery unobtrusive validation with bootstrap. Double check that you have them in the right place.

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.unobtrusive.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Try changing your BundleConfig and include all the files in the right order, avoiding the wildcards ({version} and *), try if it works. Then expeeriment and try to get wildcards right. I have something like that in my project:

```
        BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery")
            .Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"
            ));

        BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/ui")
            .Include(
                "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"
            ));

        BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/validate")
            .Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.bootstrap.min.js"
            ));
```

Comment: Yeah it is working Now,for some reasan i lost the 3 files/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.bootstrap.min.js

Answer (score 1):

Same issue.
I started a simple test by creating a VS 2012 MVC 4 internet app (out-of-the-box). I then updated jquery validation and tested. No problems. I then updated jquery (2.1.1) BAM!!!

I tried simply changing the bundle based upon last answer

Changed

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

to

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                       "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.bootstrap.min.js"));
```

And YES that fixed it!